# Django: Check if a foreign key field has been loaded

Tags: django, django-models

I have two django models

```
class ValidName:
    name = models.TextField()

class MetaSyntacticName(ValidNames):
    name = models.ForeignKey(ValidName)
    usages = models.IntegerField()
```

If I have an instance of MetaSyntacticName, can I find out if the ValidName instance it's name references has been loaded from the database without a database query?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this I could find is using a private model instance attribute `_state`. It has an attribute `fields_cache` which is a mapping: field name -> field cache.

So in your case you can check if a foreign key `name` has been loaded using this line:

`'name' in instance._state.fields_cache`

where `instance` is an instance of `MetaSyntacticName`.

The following code demonstrates that it's working:

```py
foo = ValidName.objects.create(name='foo')
foo_meta = MetaSyntacticName.objects.create(name=foo, usages=1)
'name' in foo_meta._state.fields_cache  # True
foo_meta = MetaSyntacticName.objects.get(name_id=foo.id)
'name' in foo_meta._state.fields_cache  # False
# next line hits the db and loads the field 'name'
foo_meta.name
'name' in foo_meta._state.fields_cache  # True
```

It took some time for me to hack this out so I hope this saves someone's time :)

P.S. I checked that the similar code works on Django 2.2, as `_state` is a private attribute it might be different between Django versions

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents. I guess in Django 2.x were introduced public API for this (see django.db.models.fields.mixins.FieldCacheMixin) so you can check field is cached or not by calling `MetaSyntacticName.name.is_cached(instance)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), then there won't be any extra database query for prepopulating ForeignKey related objects. For example:(copy pasted from documentation):

```
# Hits the database.
e = Entry.objects.get(id=5)

# Hits the database again to get the related Blog object.
b = e.blog
```

And here’s select_related lookup:

```
# Hits the database.
e = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').get(id=5)

# Doesn't hit the database, because e.blog has been prepopulated
# in the previous query.
b = e.blog
```

Comment: I don't want my actions to ever populate the related object. If it has been populated, and there is a reasonable chance it has, I want to interrogate the related object. But if it hasn't been populated, I just want to move on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add method like this:

```
class MetaSyntacticName(ValidNames):
    ...

    def valid_name_is_cached(self):
        return __class__.validname_ptr.is_cached(self)
```

__class__ is just MetaSyntacticName

validname_ptr - is Django descriptor which have method is_cached

Answer (score 0):

@sergei-zherevchuk's comment gives the modern answer to this question:  `MetaSyntacticName.name.is_cached(instance)` or (more generally, `Model.field_name.is_cached(model_instance)`) is now the best way to do this.

Adding this answer so that it's officially an answer when someone else comes searching.